# NSDateFormatter failed on some string but not all

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"1989-04-16"];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

I want to parse a date string @"1989-04-16". It failed. But other string will be ok, like @"1989-04-17" or @"1989-04-15". Why? Thank you very much.

I'm sorry to write the formateString with "yyyy-dd-MM", in fact "yyyy-MM-dd". And it doesn't work still. I'm in China. The timezone must be GMT +8. So i add NSTimeZone to dateFormatter and it works, just like @Amin Negm-Awad said! Thank you very much.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:3600*8];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"1989-04-16"];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

Comment: You have the day and month backwards.

Comment: @rmaddy Really weird. Even I change the order like `@"yyyy-MM-dd"`, parsing `@"1989-04-16"` will return `nil`, but parsing `@"1989-04-15"` is OK.

Comment: Sanity check - make sure all the hyphens are actually `-` characters and not some similar looking character.

Comment: Since the spelling of your name doesn't look very latin, try to set the calendar, timezone and locale properties of the formatter.

Answer (score 0):

your format is wrong :

you say yyyy-dd-MM (year / day / month ) 
but you give it a string that is yyyy-MM-dd (1989-04-17)

=> so change the format of the formatter to 'yyyy-MM-dd'

Comment: 1) It needs to be `yyyy-MM-dd`. 2) This was covered in the comments and it still doesn't work for some dates.

Comment: @rmaddy then write an answer, not a comment ;) I fix Y to y - I want this closed is all